# Do gluons have only two possible eigenvalues of helicity?

Tags: helicity, gluons

In the Standard Model, gluons are massless spin-1 bosons just as photons are, so it stands to reason that they only have two possible eigenvalues of helicity for the same reason that [photons, which are massless spin-1 bosons, have only two such values](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29766/why-does-photon-have-only-two-possible-eigenvalues-of-helicity).

But, I could imagine that I am overlooking something important in this naive analysis, and would like to confirm that gluons like photons have only two helicity states. A [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345010/do-gluons-have-properties-other-than-color-charge-that-distinguish-them-from-eac) I asked seems to reach this conclusion, but with very little analysis or resort to sources, and I'm not sure I was specific enough in focusing on this point to clearly communicate this issue, so this question refers only to helicity.

Comment: @DanielC Thank you for the edit. I appreciate your correction of my clerical error slip up.

Comment: What makes you think that the analysis made for a photon (which I hope you understood) may not be applicable to the gluon?

Comment: One concern is that, unlike photons, gluons are sometimes described as acquiring mass dynamically and I'm not sure that only "rest mass" is relevant to the analysis. *See, e.g.,*  O. Oliveira and P. Bicudo, "Running gluon mass from a Landau gauge lattice QCD propagator" (2011) J. Phys. G: Nucl. Part. Phys. 38 045003 doi:10.1088/0954-3899/38/4/045003. Another is that gluons have self-interactions that photons lack and a more complex charge structure which might be relevant.

Comment: According to the currently accepted theory (SM), the gluon is massless, yes, with "color charge", but this has no impact on the spacetime description (which follows from the Coleman-Mandula no-go theorem). Gluons cannot be directly observable, but they are +1 and -1 eigenstates of helicity.